# Does it look too bad if I apply for a different position (in different department) at a firm where I am being considered for a position?

Tags: interviewing, applications

I am currently awaiting to hear a feedback regarding the final interview I had for a position but I just saw another position that closely matches my interest and line of education & work in a different department of the same firm. I really want to apply for this new position so that it doesn't get filled/closed before I hear back from the final interview. But I am thinking doing so right now might come across as if I am not really interested in the job I had a final interview for.

My other reservation is that the hiring manager in not too many words said that he does not feel strongly about my suitability for this position. Thus, I am not really certain I will even get an offer. However, at the same time I do not want to jeopardise the result of my recent interview. Let's be honest, I will need some sort of job.

Is there anything you would suggest?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with applying for as many jobs at a company as you are qualified for. You might want to contact HR first and ask them how they prefer to handle that; they may want to simply circulate the file you already submitted to additional managers, and in some companies they may already be doing so.